# Change old value of list to new value in java

Tags: java, spring, hashmap

I am getting Date as timestamp so I convert it to only date. I am getting the result in List. I am trying to change old date value of key to new value in list. How can I do that?

```
    List<User> AllMember = newMemberDAO.getAllMember(start);

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>(); 

    for (User stu : AllMember) { 
        map.put(stu.getDateTime()); 
        System.out.println("getDateTime : " +stu.getDateTime());
         
        Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String s = formatter.format(stu.getDateTime());
        System.out.println("formatter : " +s);
        }
```

Here I am getting date from list member and convert it to the dd-MM-yyyy format but now I want change the old date value to new date but how can I do that?

Result:

Old dateTime: 2020-09-18 00:00:00.0

New dateTime: 18-09-2020

Comment: `stu.setDateTme(s)` would be the conventional way, but if `User` doesn't have a `setDateTime` method, you might be out of luck.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson User have setDateTime  method but its date not string

Comment: actually i dont want to convert date but whenever I get this date at frontend it looks like this :  1602613800000

Comment: I think this date 2020-09-03 00:00:00.0 converted into seconds like this 1602613800000. Even if I try convert these seconds into date it looks like this - +052754-09-03T20:00:00.000Z.  I dont understand what is happening here. :(

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Problem solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this date 2020-09-23 00:00:00.0 in millisconds like this 1600885800000
at the frontend. Thats why I was trying to convert Timstamp into simple date and put back to map. But I got simple solution for this.
I just display milliseconds like this:-

```
      Date in milliseconds: {{plan.dateTime}}
      Regular Date: {{plan.dateTime | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Result:

Date in milliseconds :1600885800000

Regular Date: 24/09/2020